# How to get NativeScript's slider to use step values?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using NativeScript's slider component in my app. I need the slider to only do integer values.

```
<Slider 
    width="275"
    minValue="{{ minValue }}" 
    maxValue="{{ maxValue }}" 
    [ngModel]="value" 
    (ngModelChange)='onValueChanged($event)'>
</Slider>
```

How can I get it to do integer steps only for both iOS and for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an open [Issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/535) at NativeScript.

As workaround you can try to round the value if value changed in your `onValueChanged`:

Template:

```
 <Slider #sl (valueChange)="onValueChanged(sl.value)"></Slider>
```

Component:

```
public onValueChanged(value) {
   ...
   this.value = Math.round(value);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rounding the number doesn't give me a step of 10 (i.e) so I wrote it like so:

```
onValueChanged(value) {
   let step = 10;
   this.value = Math.ceil(value / step ) * step;
}
```

html

```
<Slider #sl minValue="10" maxValue="240" (valueChange)="onValueChanged(sl.value)"></Slider>
```